# How to save Django "forms.ModelForm" in database after editing it content and passing a  javascript variable to it's new entered field

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model look like this:

```
class filled(stateobject):
    first = models.IPAddressField(verbose_name=_("First address"))
    second = models.CharField(max_length=39, verbose_name=_("Second address")
```

Embedding these model into Django-forms by following code :

```
class hostCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = filled
        widgets = {
            'user': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

In views.py:

```
def address_create(request):
if required.method=='POST':
    form = HostCreateForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    host = form.save()
    return redirect_to(request, url=host.get_absolute_url())
extra_context = {
       'form': HostCreateForm(initial={'user': request.user.pk})
    }
      return direct_to_template(request, 'networks/Address_form.html', extra_context)
```

In :Address_form.html

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

When i run above code's it shows me a form containing two fields i.e. **first** and **second**. I want to edit this form and add a new char field by named GMT, So that i am able to pass a following javascript variable i.e gmtHours in this new created field

```
var d = new Date()
var gmtHours = -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

Finally when user's click on sumbit button at template it save a form content i.e.

```
 1.  first
 2.  second
 3.  newly created gmtHours
```

I am newbie in Django-model. Want your help :)

Comment: -1 for what there is a net problem and now it's ok?

Comment: You don't want help, you want us to do this for you.

Comment: i just want a help. I put this whole code only for a resson i.e."to explain little bit more"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a hidden field to your `ModelForm` that will hold the date:

```
class hostCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = filled
        widgets = {
            'user': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
    # additional hidden field
    datetime = forms.DatetimeField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

You can then assign it a value in the javascript.

Comment: Thenx for replying.After adding above line. I print the form content but nothing change, even it was not redirect to next page. May be because we are using of Django model and Form model simultaneously.

What if i make some changes into Django model by adding a field and put into the hidden layer as we are doing with user?

Comment: That would work (the datetime will be hidden form element and saved in the db).

Comment: Sorry to say but i also checked the database it doesn't :) . Anyway now, i have an another situation would you please help in this situation: I added a time_zone model IntegerField and make hidden to it as same as i did to "user". I want to pass a java script variable to that hidden field. How can i do that. I tried with by customize the form but it doesn't work. Need your help :)